# Rich cards from V1 Bot suddenly stop working with Facebook channel

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework

My bot was working fine even a couple of days after V3 came out, the problem showed suddenly yesterday, specifically when the bot tries to render a Rich Card attachment in Facebook Messenger. Instead of the card, this message appears:

> Service Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**This is how I create a Rich Card:**

```
replyMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
replyMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
{
    Title = product.productName,
    ThumbnailUrl = product.images[0],
    Text = product.storeName,
    Actions = new List<Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action>() {
        new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Action() {
            Title = Resources.es.VER,
            Message = Resources.es.CALCULAR + " " + product.link
        }
    }
});
```

Local tests and the test connection module available in my bot framework portal work as expected without any problems. Since is a V1 Bot, the Rich card attachment uses the deprecated way of doing this, however the documentation suggests that the old way should still work but it doesn't with the Facebook channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I just needed to add the property ContentUrl = String.Empty to the attachment and now it works like normal.